# Kion signifas "rekcio"?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning-in-context

En la [PDF](https://edukado.net/upload/enhavo/dosieroj/Ekzamenoj/Esperanto%20de%20nivelo%20al%20nivelo_reta_preta_korektita3maju%2028.pdf) havebla ĉe [edukado.net](https://edukado.net) > [Ekzamenoj](https://edukado.net/ekzamenoj) > [UEA-KER](https://edukado.net/ekzamenoj/ker) > [Specimenoj](https://edukado.net/ekzamenoj/ker/specimenoj), en paĝo 19 (lingvokonaj postuloj por supera nivelo (C1) > Morfologio kaj vortsintakso) estas listita

> Verbaj rekcioj.

Kion signifas "rekcio"? Mi ne trovis tiun vorton en vortaroj. Kio estas "verbaj rekcioj"? Aŭ ĉu tiu estas nur tajperaro en la dokumento? Se ĝi estas tajperaro, kio estu la ĝusta vorto?

Comment: Rimarketo: estas tajperaro en la titolo de la demando.

Comment: Ĉu vi celas "Kio" -> "Kion", @EduardoTrápani? Mi nun korektis tion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Povas esti, ke la termino mem estas neologismo, sed la termino "rekcio" estas vaste uzata en aliaj lingvoj.

Temas pri tio, kiel oni aligas vortojn al verboj, ĉu per la akuzativo aŭ per iu prepozicio.

Ekzemploj:

- la rekcio por la verbo "havi" estas per la akuzativo: havi ion
- la rekcio por la verbo "temi" estas per la prepozicio "pri": temi pri io
- la rekcio por la verbo "bazi" estas per la prepozicio "sur": bazi sur io

Comment: Ĉi tio respondo kongruas kun [tio, kion Mirejo skribis](https://t.me/EsperantoILEI/810) en https://ilei.telegramo.org kaj ja sencas rilate al similaj vortoj en aliaj lingvoj, do mi akceptas ĝin.

Answer (score 1):

Mi ne scias precise, sed verŝajne ĝi estas [scienca] neologismo por
«verba uzado».  Ekzemple, en la angla ekzistas la vorto «*rection*» (de
la latina «*rectio*»), kiun la angla Vikivortaro
[difinas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rection) kiel:

> (grammar, archaic) regimen; government; the rules governing the
> syntax, rules of agreement of a language.

Similaj vortoj ekzistas en la germana («*[die] Rektion*»), la
nederlanda («*[de] rectie*»), kaj eĉ la suoma («*rektio*»).

Comment: Kvankam ĉi tio respondo ŝajnas havi la ĝustan direkton kaj la efektivan etimologion, [la respondo de Juha](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5999/1576) estas pli preciza, do mi akceptis tiun, ne ĉi tiun. Tamen dankon!